# PHP for loop count from select list

Tags: php, for-loop

I am working on a project and am still relatively new to PHP. I am attempting to run a for loop which counts the number of times each flower is selected from a select list off of an HTML page. I am continuously getting "1" for all 3 flower types after choosing different combinations from the select lists during testing. If anyone has any input as to where my mistakes are I would greatly appreciate it! Here is my HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>FLOWERS</h1>
        <form action = 'php 08.php' method = 'post'>

            <select id = '0' name = '0'>

                <option value = 'marigold'>marigold</option>
                <option value = 'rose'>rose</option>
                <option value = 'tulip'>tulip</option>

            </select>

            <br><br>

            <select id = '1' name = '1'>

                <option value = 'marigold'>marigold</option>
                <option value = 'rose'>rose</option>
                <option value = 'tulip'>tulip</option>

            </select>

            <br><br>

            <select id = '2' name = '2'>

                <option value = 'marigold'>marigold</option>
                <option value = 'rose'>rose</option>
                <option value = 'tulip'>tulip</option>

            </select>

            <br><br>

            <select id = '3' name = '3'>

                <option value = 'marigold'>marigold</option>
                <option value = 'rose'>rose</option>
                <option value = 'tulip'>tulip</option>

            </select>

            <br><br>

            <select id = '4' name = '4'>

                <option value = 'marigold'>marigold</option>
                <option value = 'rose'>rose</option>
                <option value = 'tulip'>tulip</option>

            </select>

            <br><br>

            <input type = 'submit' id = 'go' value = 'COUNT'>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

$marigold = $_POST['marigold'];

$rose = $_POST['rose'];

$tulip = $_POST['tulip'];

for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {

    if ($i == 'marigold') {

        $marigold++;

    };

    if ($i == 'rose') {

        $rose++;

    };

    if ($i == 'tulip') {

        $tulip++;

    };

};

echo "MARIGOLD <span id = 'marigold'>$marigold</span>";

echo "<br><br>";

echo "ROSE <span id = 'rose'>$rose</span>";

echo "<br><br>";

echo "TULIP <span id = 'tulip'>$tulip</span>";

?>
```

Comment: `if ($i == 'marigold')` makes no sense. `i` is a number from `0` to `4`, how can it be a flower name?

Comment: What is `$_POST['marigold']` supposed to be? That would come from a form input with `name="marigold"`, but there's nothing like that in your HTML. You have `name="0"`, `name="1"`, and so on, so those would be in `$_POST['0']`, `$_POST['1']`, etc. I think you need to read a tutorial on how to process HTML forms with PHP, since you're extremely confused about the basics.

Comment: For starters HTML `id` and `name` attributes must start with an alpha value.

Comment: @PHPglue That restriction was removed in HTML5, I believe.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I see what you mean. So instead should I be substituting the id values from the select lists?

Comment: @Barmar I apologize. This is one of my first few assignments in PHP from a programming course I'm taking. Still trying to get the hang of things.

Comment: @SamB Don't write ; at end of if brace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your HTML like this, your PHP code should be like that:

```
//Initialise your counter
$marigold=$rose=$tulip=0

for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {

    if ($_POST[$i] == 'marigold') {
        $marigold++;
    }

    if ($_POST[$i] == 'rose') {
        $rose++;
    }

    if ($_POST[$i] == 'tulip') {   
        $tulip++;    
    }

}

echo "MARIGOLD <span id = 'marigold'>$marigold</span>";

echo "<br><br>";

echo "ROSE <span id = 'rose'>$rose</span>";

echo "<br><br>";

echo "TULIP <span id = 'tulip'>$tulip</span>";
```

Comment: Why use the variable variable? Just use `if ($_POST[$i] == 'marigold')`

Comment: BTW, you're missing `$select0`.

Comment: @Barmar Because I wanted to keep the code structure the most similar to the original. But it's better like that

Comment: @WilliamPerron That was able to resolve my issue! So, for future reference, you don't always need to use a variable with "$_POST"?

Comment: @SamB. In your case, it's more dynamic with a variable. But $_POST['1'],$_POST['2'],etc. is the same, normaly use a better name like "flower1" for your <select> that will be easier to understand.

Comment: @SamB. And id="1" is useless in that example.